# Polymorphic Argument Lists in Python

Tags: python

I want to expose a method with an polymorphic argument list interface:

```
def my_method(*args: Union[str, Type[MyType], Dict[str, Dict[str, str]] ):
    pass
```

The context is that I want to allow a way to register `MyType` along with initializer parameters. MyType has a name property that is a string. (This is useful because multiple classes can map to the same name, and the category of classes is runtime selectable). `Dict[str, Dict[str, str]]` maps this string name to the arguments to be passed to the matching class of the string.

So the client can call:

```
my_method("my_special_class"
           FastMySpecialClass,
           {"my_special_class": {"arg1": "foo", "arg2", "bar"}}
)
```

Now in `my_method()` the only thing I can think to handle this is with an `isinstance()` switch/case. Either with `elseif` or some dict of type to handler function. Kind of like this:

```
for arg in args:
    argument_resolver[type(arg)](arg)
```

My instincts tell me that this is a horrible way to handle polymorphism, but I can't come up with something better.

Comment: This sounds like a good use case for [`functools.singledispatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch)

Comment: Using a `dict` is the basic way this would be done in Python. You essentially want function overloading based on the type of a paramter, i.e. ad-hoc polymorphism. Python doesn't support this, nor do any dynamically typed languages I know of. Perhaps there is a better way to design your overall program, but what you've proposed is reasonable enough given the specific use-case you describe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For less complex scenarios, I'd suggest [using `functools.singledispatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch). Trying to make this work for a varargs scenario would be fairly ugly though. Best solution I can think of would have a separate function that is called by `my_method` on each element of the `args` `tuple`, and have that separate function implemented with `functools.singledispatch`.

To be clear, under the hood, `functools.singledispatch` is effectively just doing a slightly optimized version of `isinstance` checking (it maintains a `dict` mapping types to implementing functions; if the *exact* type is registered, the lookup is `O(1)`, but for subclasses and ABCs and the like, it has to fall back to linear scan). But it's generally cleaner looking than mixing it all in one function that implements the behavior for a whole mess of types.

Comment: Very similar to the `argument_resolver[type(arg)](arg)` idea but with a built-in. I'll try it.

Comment: But then again, is this `isinstance` checking fundamentally even the right approach?

Comment: @BaconPancakes: I'd suspect [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/322040) here myself (forgot to mention that in the answer), because yeah, it's not a great solution, and this is an odd thing to do, but in Python, there isn't any better solution to the specific problem you posed. If you have a higher-level problem X and this is the Y you're trying to solve it with, there might be better solutions to X, but Python doesn't really offer a better solution than `isinstance` checking for the Y as posed.

Comment: The best solution in other languages might be an overloaded function (e.g. as in C++, where it's resolved at compile-time, while Python's equivalent `singledispatch` can't be implemented with anything but runtime dispatch) or a method with a common name defined for each type (this would get you better performance when all the options are user-defined types, but Python won't let you monkey-patch built-ins, so you can't attach your new method to `str` or `dict`).